# Django python: no such column:

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

I used a form to create a django post with a single "text" field. Then I modified the post model. Now there are three forms "author", "body" and "title". Also changed the mentions in home.html and other files. Logically, it should work, but it gives an error in the file home.html

> there is no such column: pages_posts.title
> error in line 5

Some files from my project:

`views.py`

```python
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, CreateView, DetailView
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Posts


class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Posts
    template_name = 'home.html'
#    post_list = Posts.title
#    context_object_name = 'all_posts_list'


class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'


class SignUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'


class NewPostUpView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'


class BlogDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Posts
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


class BlogCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Posts
    template_name = 'post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body']
```

`models.py`

```python
from django.db import models


class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='False')
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
```

`home.html`

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% for post in object_list %}
    <div class="post-entry">
      <h2><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
      <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

`base.html`

```html
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Django blog</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400"
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <header>
        <div class="nav-left">
          <a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> | <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
        </div>
      </header>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3>Hi {{ user.username }}!</h3>
        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></p>
        <div class="nav-right">
          <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">+ New Blog Post</a>
        </div>
      {% else %}
        <p>You are not logged in.</p>
        <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log In</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you run migrations ?

Comment: You need to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

The title, body and author fields cannot be null. If you initially create these fields, there will be no error. But if we edit the `post` model, then we create fields for which there is no value in the `pages` table in this case. Then if we create new fields, we need to write a **default** value for each of them.

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='') 
author =models.ForeignKey(
    'auth.User',
    default='',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
body = models.TextField(default='')
```

After these manipulations, do not forget to update the migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```